# Different select criteria in odd and even events

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which looks like this ( 10 billion rows)

---

```
 AID  BID  CID     
  1    2    1
  1    6    9 
  0    1    4 
  1    3    2 
  1    100  2 
  0    4    2 
  0    0    1
```

---

The AID could only be 0 or 1. BID and CID could be anything. 
Now I want to select events first with AID=1 and then AID=0, and again AID=1 and then AID=0. 
The idea is to select equal numbers of AID=1 and AID=0 event.
How can I achieve that?

The expected result is

```
AID   BID   CID     
  1     2     1     
  0     1     4     
  1     6     9     
  0     4     2     
  1     3     2     
  0     0     1
```

Comment: What would be the expected result here?

Comment: Please provide the desired result and the query you have tried (if there is any). You explanation is not clear.

Comment: Please post what you've tried till now. And how it has failed. Till then, it is just another "give me the codez" question.

Comment: I think he wants to see alternating, 1 then 0 rows based on AID. What would you want to happen in the event that there are an uneven number of AID=0 and 1 events?

Comment: Hi all,  I don't know how to do that therefore I am asking. I know how to select events based on certain criteria. But I don't know how to do with  different criteria for different rows.

Comment: @Mrk421 try my answer, is that what you needed?

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ I take this kind of questions as a challenge :) Sometimes it is very interesting to find the answers, even if there are not rewarded.

Answer (score 3):

```
;WITH cte AS (
select *
FROM (VALUES
(1, 2, 1),
(1, 6, 9),
(0, 1, 4),
(1, 3, 2),
(1, 100, 2), 
(0, 4, 2), 
(0, 0, 1)
) as t(AID, BID, CID)
),
withrow AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AID ORDER BY AID) as RN, *
FROM cte)

SELECT AID,BID,CID
FROM withrow 
ORDER BY RN asc , aid desc
```

Output:

```
AID         BID         CID
----------- ----------- -----------
1           100         2
0           4           2
1           3           2
0           1           4
1           6           9
0           0           1
1           2           1

(7 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Yes.. this approach got to me also while reading the question .. but as it was for sqlserver I needed to check for the feasibility (I use Oracle Database)..

Comment: Thanks, it was quick :), I am a newbie in SQL.

Comment: @pratikgarg never worked with Oracle :( unfortunately.